# Make spreadsheet only editable through script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script which adds new rows and changes the sheet in some ways.
I'd like to lock this sheet so it cannot be edited manually, but allow the script to be run.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's not the most easier thing to do, but it's possible.

But before we start it's important to understand how Google spreadsheet/sheet protection works.

There's no way to protect a sheet or range from the file owner. So, if you also want to protect a file from yourself (assuming you're the owner). Then the only solution available now (I do hope they change this in the future) is to change the ownership of the file to another account. What most people do is use another Google account that they don't use actively (you can create a bogus easily if you don't already have one).

Then, after you have transferred the file to another account, you can easily lock changes to ranges, sheets or the whole spreadsheet using the regular GUI.

Ok, now to the script. When a script runs, it's always using the authorization of a specific account, and it can do everything that this account can. For example, when someone runs a script directly from the script editor, or clicking on a custom menu or image: it runs under the account of who's clicking. But if you set a [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers#ActionTriggers), then the script always runs under the account of who setup the trigger in the first place (not who's performing the action that actually triggers it). [Simple event triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers#Simple) run as who's triggering the action (you can think anonymously), but they can't do much, it's a security feature (read the link for a better understanding).

Lastly, when one is publishing a script as a web-app, then there's a selection box to choose if the script runs as the developer or the user. Very simple.

Back to the problem. Since we have locked out everybody from the desired sheet/range. For a script to make changes to this locked area, it must run as the file owner!

If the changes you do are automatic, e.g. via a installable trigger, then you're good. Just setup the trigger using the file owner account and that's it. Also, if your users are accessing the script "externally", that is, via a web-app. Then that's easy to, just setup the web-app to run as the developer (the file owner).

The most complicated scenario is if you need to run the script from a custom menu, which will then run under the privileges of who's clicking on it, which themselves can not make changes to the protected area. The solution to this is to deploy the script as web-app running as the developer, and have the function running from the button click to call the deployed url using [UrlFetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/), possibly passing some parameters to designate what needs to be done. Then, since the webapp runs as the developer (which is the file owner), it can make any changes required, and return (if there's something to return) any value (usually a JSON) to the calling function (which is running as the user and is associated with his session), so you can show him a message on a popup or toaster, etc.

It's kind of tricky but works great, and you can do all that on the same script contained in the spreadsheet. But if you're concerned that your users may access the script editor and change the code (which is possible), than you should separate the web-app part on a different file, that you don't need to share with them.

Comment: Although I've asked this long ago, I have only recently begun to implement this. To prevent users from being able to view and edit the script, does the file need to be in another account? I couldn't find any sharing-related setting when creating an script.

Comment: The Apps Script team have changed how sharing works for Spreadsheet container-bounded scripts, [see here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2012#june_8_2012). So now, as suggested by them, if you want to protect the code, you'll have to use libraries, but still, the contained code that imports the library will still be editable.

Comment: This answer is a couple years old. Any updates on how this can be done today (2019?). I'm not finding much.

Comment: AFAIK the permissions model still all work the same. This answer is still up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but only for others not for the script owner. Just use 2 accounts one as the owner and the other one as the reader.